# Euler's formula for connected, planar graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

So I have to prove the graph in the picture is planar using Euler's formula $v - e + f = 2.$ It obviously is planar, but the formula for it is $9 - 12 + 6 = 3$. What am I doing wrong?

[image: graph]

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!!

Comment: If you check the wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula you see that "Euler's formula states that if a finite, *connected*, planar graph is drawn in the plane...." that the graph needs to be connected. Otherwise, you can just keep adding vertices connected to nothing and vertex count will go up but the e and f values will stay the same.

Comment: @manooooh you need to count infinite face too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > I have to prove the graph in the picture is planar using Euler's formula

You can't prove planarity using Euler's formula. You can sometimes prove the opposite: that graph is not planar, by using Euler's formula and fact that each face in planar graph has at least 3 edges. (which will get your criteria that in planar graph it should be that $E \leq 3V - 6$).

2. Euler's formula is for *connected* graphs. If your graph is disconnected, calculate Euler's formula for each connected part separately. Alternatively you can use formula $V - E + F = k + 1$, where k $-$ number of connected components.